# Process xml files and move to another folder

Tags: c#, xml

Having processed each xml file, I need to move it to another folder. What is the code to do this and where to put it, ensuring that if a file with same name in target exists, then this is overwritten

```
                string Path1 = @"D:\dataIn";
                string Path2 = @"D:\dataOut";

                con.Open();
                label1.Text = "";

                foreach (string file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(Path1, "*.xml"))
                {
                    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                    ds.ReadXml(file);
                    DataTable dt1 = ds.Tables["Order"];
                    DataTable dt2 = ds.Tables["Details"];
                    using (SqlBulkCopy bc = new SqlBulkCopy(con))
                    {
                        bc.ColumnMappings.Add("account", "account");
                        bc.ColumnMappings.Add("date", "date");
                        bc.ColumnMappings.Add("value", "value");
                        bc.DestinationTableName = "header";
                        bc.WriteToServer(dt1);
                    }
                    using (SqlBulkCopy bc = new SqlBulkCopy(con))
                    {
                        bc.ColumnMappings.Add("itemID", "itemID");
                        bc.ColumnMappings.Add("qty", "qty");
                        bc.ColumnMappings.Add("price", "price");
                        bc.DestinationTableName = "items";
                        bc.WriteToServer(dt2);
                    }                    
                }
```

Comment: Look at System.IO.File class

Answer (score 0):

You may be looking for `File.Move`.

Don't forget the IO namespace:

```
using System.IO;
```

And then the code to move the file, which you'll put at the end of the for loop:

```
if (File.Exists(newFile)) // Did we find the file?
{
    File.Delete(newFile); // Yep, so delete it.
}
File.Move(file, newFile); // Move the file.
```

You can also use `File.Copy`, but then you'd have to delete the file if you want to "move" it.

Here's what you'd do to your foreach loop:

```
            foreach (string file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(Path1, "*.xml"))
            {
                string newFile = path2 + @"\" + Path.GetFileName(file);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                ds.ReadXml(file);
                DataTable dt1 = ds.Tables["Order"];
                DataTable dt2 = ds.Tables["Details"];
                using (SqlBulkCopy bc = new SqlBulkCopy(con))
                {
                    bc.ColumnMappings.Add("account", "account");
                    bc.ColumnMappings.Add("date", "date");
                    bc.ColumnMappings.Add("value", "value");
                    bc.DestinationTableName = "header";
                    bc.WriteToServer(dt1);
                }
                using (SqlBulkCopy bc = new SqlBulkCopy(con))
                {
                    bc.ColumnMappings.Add("itemID", "itemID");
                    bc.ColumnMappings.Add("qty", "qty");
                    bc.ColumnMappings.Add("price", "price");
                    bc.DestinationTableName = "items";
                    bc.WriteToServer(dt2);
                }

                if (File.Exists(newFile)) // Did we find the file?
                {
                    File.Delete(file); // Yep, so delete it.
                }
                File.Move(file, newFile); 
           }
```

Comment: Do I put these lines in just before the last curly brace ?

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake. With the old code, you'd be deleting the original file, which is bad. With the new code, you need to set `newFile` to the location where you'd expect to move it. Check the updated code, and it should be clear to you. If you need any more help, please let me know.

Comment: You're right. It deleted my files.  I don't understand "set newFile to the location where you expect to move it". I want the file to go to Path2. Is that correct ?

Comment: My apologies. You could do something like this: `File.Move(file, path2 + @"\" + Path.GetFileName(file));` I'll update the code.

Comment: The code is updated. Let me know if that works! I think it should. Just for reference, the @ symbol before the string allows you to mark the string as a verbatim string literal, allowing you to ignore escape sequences. Basically, instead of writing string test = "C:\\windows\\system32\\";, you can just write string test = @"C:\windows\system32\";. Ignore the formatting colors; stack overflow doesn't know how to parse that. :-P

Answer (score 0):

`File.Copy` will copy the file, overwriting any existing file with that name.
See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6cfw35a(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: True, but OP specifically stated he wanted to "move" the file. Copying it will require the extra step of deleting the old file.

Comment: got a squiggly line  if (File.Exists(newFile)) // Did we find the file?  underneath newfile